# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API - returns all errors as JSON

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

ASP.NET Core returns (if error) only HTTP status code and empty body. Is it possible to handle all errors?

I would like return HTTP status code and json? For example

```
{
    "status": STATUS_CODE,
    "message": "error"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filters for this. Create a filter similar to this:

```
 public class HandledResultFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        var error = new HandledResult<Exception>(context.Exception).HandleException();

        context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json").ToString();
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = error.StatusCode;
        context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(error), Encoding.UTF8);
    }
}
```

And register it:

```
services.AddMvc(mvcOptions =>
            {
                mvcOptions.Filters.Add(new HandledResultFilter());
            });
```

Comment: I don't use MVC, it's simple rest api.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own middleware to handle any errors and return to the client any information you want.

You can place the middleware in the `Startup. Configure` method before any other middleware and before controller endpoint mappings to handle every error.

Details are in this article: [Error Handler Tutorial for ASP NET](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/10/02/aspnet-core-31-global-error-handler-tutorial)

Comment: Thank you, but this middleware doesn't catch eg. BadRequest, NotFound exceptions (only 500)